# How to avoid an easily made deadlock?

Tags: java, locking, deadlock

I have an object User with two locks, inventoryLock and currencyLock. Often these locks will be used individually, e.g.

```
synchronized (user.inventoryLock) {

 // swap items
 tmp = user.inventory[x];
 user.inventory[x] = user.inventory[y];
 user.inventory[y] = tmp;

}
```

or

```
synchronized (user.currencyLock) {

 if (user.money < loss) throw new Exception();
 user.money -= loss;

}
```

But sometimes a piece of code requires both locks:

```
synchronized (user.currencyLock) {
 synchronized (user.inventoryLock) {

  if (user.money < item.price) throw new Exception();
  user.money -= item.price;
  user.inventory[empty] = item;

 }
}
```

Seems simple, but there are more bits of code using both locks than just this example, and I know from previous experience that if multiple pieces of code require the same shared locks, they have a risk of deadlocking.

What's a good way to avoid that?

Is there maybe some kind of mechanism that will let me atomically lock on two objects?

Comment: Your code shows a serious lack of encapsulation. You access the state of the user directly, without going through methods. The state should be encapsulated in the class, which would centralize synchronization, and make sure that all the necessary synchronization is done. You're forcing every client of your user to synchronize properly, rather than providing this service in the User class itself.

Comment: @JBNizet This is just example code. The real code involves, among other things, database calls which the user class is not capable of performing.

Answer (score 3):

always lock one lock before the other, one of the requirements of a deadlock is a circular waiting pattern

for example if you can ensure that you will always lock `currencyLock` before you lock `inventoryLock` and never attempt to lock `currencyLock` when you already have `inventoryLock` you will be fine

Comment: This is what I came up with too, so I can't help but agree :)

Comment: You can't help locking one before the other. You must *always acquire the locks in the same order.*

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting this question I came up with a simple solution myself: Just make sure all the code acquires the locks in the same order. That way there can never be two thread both holding one of them.

If there is no natural order, alphabetical would suffice and be easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any [circular wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_wait) possibilities here, which is 1 of 4 conditions necessary for deadlock.

Comment: There are more pieces of code that require both locks, not just the one example I posted. I'll clarify that.